# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'AuthFirstName' not found on type entity.Authors

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el, propertynotfoundexception

Entity:

```
package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Authors implements Serializable {

    private String AuthFirstName;

    public Authors() {
    }

    public String getAuthFirstName() {
        return AuthFirstName;
    }

    public void setAuthFirstName(String AuthFirstName) {
        this.AuthFirstName = AuthFirstName;
    }

}
```

Servlet:

```
 List listAuthors = authDAO.findAuthors();
 request.setAttribute("lista", listAuthors);
```

JSP:

```html
<c:forEach var="var" items="${lista}">
    <c:out value="${var.AuthFirstName}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Exception:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'AuthFirstName' not found on type entity.Authors

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should start with lowercase.

```html
<c:out value="${var.authFirstName}" />
```

Further, it would also be nice to fix the underlying property name to start with lowercase as well, although it does functionally not harm.

```
private String authFirstName;
```

#### See also:

- [Javabeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138795.html)
- [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367).